# Java inputstream read() not get full byte array data

Tags: java, bluetooth, embedded, inputstream

embedded system project in which i will get some response from my microcontroller to android device using bluetooth module and i cant get the bytes from this line `bytes = "mmInStream.read(buffer)"`..
when i convert the byte[] buffer into String using this 
`String data=new String(bytes)` I dont get data that i had sent from my microcontroller properly. Sometimes charactors are missing..

```
     public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytes;

        // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

                String data=new String(bytes);         
                System.out.println(data);          

                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                connectionLost();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Please Help me

Comment: use new String(buffer , 0 , bytes) instead of new String(bytes) and the data should display properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()) instead.

> It reads text from a character-input stream, buffering characters so
>   as to provide for the efficient reading of characters, arrays, and
>   lines.

If you use Java 7 or older the following code will help:

```
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mmInStream))){
        String line = null;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
        }
        connectionLost();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

If you use Java 6 or younger than use this code:

```
BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mmInStream));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (reader != null) {
        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
        connectionLost();
    }
```

But this approach has disadvantages. You can read about them, e.g. [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/trywithresources-401775.html)